# form-login attribute doesn't change anything

Tags: java, spring

I'm totally confused by working of the spring security. I'm using `Spring Security 4.0.0.RC1`

The issue is that I couldn't configure `login-form` attribute. It just work as by default (`login-page="/login"` by default) despite changing the attribute to different values. Let me show what actually I've done.

1.

Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="login">
    <label for="user">User: </label>
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" /> </br>
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /> </br>
    <input type="submit" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

`spring-security` config:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" 
                    access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
                default-target-url="/admin" 
                authentication-failure-url="/loginn?error=true" 
                username-parameter="user"
                password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/loginn?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

Note, that the action attribute is setted to "login". Yes, it works fine. I can authenticate and if I tried to insert invalid data I'd get an error. But the following example is the most confusing.

2.

Form

```
<form method="POST" action="loginn">
    <label for="user">User: </label>
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" /> </br>
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /> </br>
    <input type="submit" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" 
                    access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/loginn" 
                default-target-url="/admin" 
                authentication-failure-url="/loginn?error=true" 
                username-parameter="user"
                password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/loginn?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

And it doesn't work. When I tried to submit the login form I just get the page back and it doesn't matter if I pass valid or invalid cridentials. But If I replace the action attribute of the form as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action="login">
    <label for="user">User: </label>
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" /> </br>
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /> </br>
    <input type="submit" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

it will work fine and I can authorize with specified authorities and be redirected to the `authentication-failure-url` if sent cridentials is invalid.

So I guess the login-page is not working. Where am I worng in that cofiguration? Maybe I should provide an additional information?

Comment: The `login-page` attribute is the name of the page to use for a login form. What you are looking for is the `login-processing-url` which is `/login` by default (it was `/j_spring_security_check` in earlier versions). So in the changed version you only changed the name of the page to use for login not the url that is actually processing the login.

Comment: @M.Deinum So what is the `login-page` for. I don't have to place a login form exactly in the url specified in the `login-page` attribute. BTW, If go to the `login-page` url it'll be rendered default spring-security login form .How can I remove that form?

Comment: As I stated it is for specifying the the URL of the login page, when one is found at that URL that is rendered else it will fallback to the default form for spring security. I would suggest a read of the reference guide as all of that is explained.